# Powerpoint Animation Automation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to add few pictures(say 3 pictures) on to the slide and then set the animation effects to each picture using VBA. I want to control the order of animation along with animation type and the duration between each animation. Please help. Below is the code I have written.

```
    Set MainSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    Set BG1 = MainSlide.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Sandhya_PPT_Task\Picture1.png", msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0, 959.76, 540)
    Set BG2 = MainSlide.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Sandhya_PPT_Task\Picture2.png", msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0, 959.76, 540)
    With BG2.AnimationSettings
        .EntryEffect = ppEffectFade
        .AnimationOrder = 1
        .AdvanceMode = ppAdvanceAfterPrevious
        .AdvanceTime = 0.5
    End With
    Set BG3 = MainSlide.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Sandhya_PPT_Task\Picture3.png", msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 90, 959.76, 429.84)
    With BG3.AnimationSettings
        .EntryEffect = ppEffectFade
        .AnimationOrder = 2
        .AdvanceMode = ppAdvanceAfterPrevious
        .AdvanceTime = 0.5
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include a full code example, and ensure that you use option explicit. Suggest changing .AdvanceMode to ppAdvanceOnTime. For example:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CreateAnimation()

    Dim MainSlide As Slide
    Dim BG1 As Shape
    Dim BG2 As Shape
    Dim BG3 As Shape

    Set MainSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    Set BG1 = MainSlide.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Sandhya_PPT_Task\Picture1.png", msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0, 959.76, 540)

    Set BG2 = MainSlide.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Sandhya_PPT_Task\Picture2.png", msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 0, 959.76, 540)
    With BG2.AnimationSettings
        .EntryEffect = ppEffectFade
        .AnimationOrder = 1
        .AdvanceMode = ppAdvanceOnTime
        .AdvanceTime = 0.5
    End With

    Set BG3 = MainSlide.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Sandhya_PPT_Task\Picture3.png", msoFalse, msoTrue, 0, 90, 959.76, 429.84)
    With BG3.AnimationSettings
        .EntryEffect = ppEffectFade
        .AnimationOrder = 2
        .AdvanceMode = ppAdvanceOnTime
        .AdvanceTime = 0.5
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are (both) using the legacy code from pre version 2002. You need to use the newer Timeline object

```
Sub animate_Pics()
Dim Pic1 As Shape
Dim pic2 As Shape
Dim pic3 As Shape
Dim osld As Slide
Dim oeff As Effect
Set osld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
Set Pic1 = osld.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\xx\Desktop\john1.jpg", msoFalse, msoTrue, 10, 10)
Pic1.Name = "John1"
Set pic2 = osld.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\xx\Desktop\john2.jpg", msoFalse, msoTrue, 10, 10)
pic2.Name = "John2"
Set pic3 = osld.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\xx\Desktop\john3.jpg", msoFalse, msoTrue, 10, 10)
pic3.Name = "John3"
Set oeff = osld.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(Pic1, msoAnimEffectFade, , msoAnimTriggerOnPageClick)
oeff.Timing.Duration = 2
Set oeff = osld.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(pic2, msoAnimEffectFade, , msoAnimTriggerOnPageClick)
oeff.Timing.Duration = 2
oeff.MoveTo 2
Set oeff = osld.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(pic3, msoAnimEffectFade, , msoAnimTriggerOnPageClick)
oeff.Timing.Duration = 2
oeff.MoveTo 3
```

End Sub